# checkbox moving control down when added to listitem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an html listitem that is populated with controls. When I add a checkbox into the listitem all the controls move down as shown in the picture. When I remove it from the list it's ok. what am I doing wrong please?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Show the relevant aspx, css, html code.

Comment: Seems some `style` issue. Check the style after adding checkbox.

Comment: Hi, I've added a Jfiddle but it only shows the code. http://jsfiddle.net/3my8g57n/